# Access tabs of browser via java code

Tags: java, browser, tabs

I want to choose certain tabs of a browser via java code. For example , I want to access 3rd or the last tab of browser and oper some web page over there. Is there a way ?

Comment: only if you write a browser app like in google chrome

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth looking at how something like adobe brackets does this.  It uses the developer mode in chrome (I think) which allows it to interact with tabs in chrome.  However I don;t know if this is available in a non developer mode.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible.
You can probably do that if you are having your own browser running in java.